# Why Apache doesn't gzip css or js files which have parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, gzip, httpd.conf, mod-deflate

Some CSS & JS files are not compressed by apache with mod_deflate enabled. This files looks like this "[domain.name]/aggregator.css?..." or "[domain.name]/misc/jquery.js?..." in YSlow. The other CSS & JS without the "?" gets compressed. Kindly explain me how do I make apache compress this files also.

Thanks

Comment: Might be more relevant to serverfault.com, assuming it is a server config issue and not programming as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about serving files with query strings, they should in general still be compressed (they are on my server).

Unless there's something funny about the way you set up your OutputFilter? Let's see some httpd.conf. Where's the server?

eta:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
```

Curious — works for me, unless there's something else broken in the config stopping it. It might be better to use the more usual:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain
```

though. (Then it will only try to deflate PHP scripts' output when they're those types and not, say, if you're spitting out an image.)

Comment: i added the following line on the .htaccess file <IfModule mod_deflate.c>  <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE </FilesMatch> </IfModule>

Comment: Uhh, I'm using 1&1 hosting which has mod_deflate and mod_gzip disabled.

Anyone in a similar situation may find this useful: http://mrrena.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-compress-php-and-other-text.html

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem -- apparently text/javascript wasn't good enough. Adding application/javascript to the filter did the trick for me.